# DataTables JSON data

Tags: html, json, datatables

I have a requirement where i have to send in data to datatables from JSON object. So i did the following:

```
$('#example').dataTable( { "data": dataSet, "columns": 
[
  { "title": "Engine" , "data" : "fieldName1"},
  { "title": "Browser", "data" : "fieldName2"},
  { "title": "Platform", "data" : "fieldName3"},
  { "title": "Version",  "data" : "fieldName4"},
  { "title": "Grade", "data" : "fieldName5"}
]
});
```

In addition, i also need to add a check box and in another column i need to add an edit link to all rows, so i tried the following:

```
{ "title": "<button>Delete Selected</button>" , "?????" : "??I need to add a check box here????"},
{ "title": "Edit" , "?????" : "??I need to add a edit link here????"},
{ "title": "Browser", "data" : "fieldName2"},
{ "title": "Platform", "data" : "fieldName3"},
{ "title": "Version",  "data" : "fieldName4"},
{ "title": "Grade", "data" : "fieldName5"}
```

How do i add those checkboxes and edit links. Edit link will only work for each row individually. The delete Selected button should delete all the rows with checkboxes selected

Answer (score 0):

Link:

```
{
    'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
            return "<a href='\'/Edit/'" + row[1] + "'>Edit</a>";
    }
}
```

Checkbox:

```
{
'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
       return "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox' id="'chk-" + row[1] + "'">";
    }
}
```

This will create links and checkboxes on each row, you will have to create the delete functionality yourself. Have a look at the [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The following worked for me:

```
{ "title": "<button>Delete Selected</button>", "data":null, "defaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' />" },
{ "title": "Edit", "data":null,"defaultContent": "<a href='#' id='EditBtn' onclick='EditButtonClick()'  />Edit" },
```

Keep Data as null and use the default content for any HTML tags like Checkboxes, radio buttons, buttons, edit links.